# comma separated auto complete with jquery not working with javascript json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i am trying to create a comma separated auto complete text field for which the auto complete json data comes from java script itself.. see my code below:

the java script array:

```
   var remark = [
        "is under construction",
        "is a part of another construction.",
        "has acquired other work.",
        "Could not source construction."
    ];
```

the auto complete method:

```
   $("#remark").bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON(JSON.stringify(remark), { //this line is the issue..
                term: extractLast(request.term)
            }, response);
        },
        search: function() {
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 2) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(",");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

the helper functions:

```
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
```

the `var remark` holds the the data for auto complete to show to the users...

the `$.getJSON(JSON.stringify(remark)` is fetching the data for auto complete..functionality but this is not working as aspect ed.. while this works when i use to fetch the data from mysql server.. but when i am using it with java script array it is not working..

any help or suggestion would be a great help.. thanks in advance...

Comment: Just using `source: remark,` in the autocomplete definition does not work?

Comment: no @mccannf sir.. its not working.. any idea..

Answer (score 0):

The [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) property directly accepts an array as data source. So you can directly pass the local array to the source property:

```
var remark = [
"is under construction",
"is a part of another construction.",
"has acquired other work.",
"Could not source construction."];

$("#remark").bind("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}).autocomplete({
  source: remark,
  search: function () {
    var term = extractLast(this.value);
    if (term.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
  },
  focus: function () {
    return false;
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);
    terms.pop();
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join(",");
    return false;
  }
});

function split(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
}
function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3c4hvov/)

Comment: thanks sir, this is working but only for once, i mean when i type first time its give me the suggestion but after that when i type comma and try to look for second suggestion its not showing.. i would like to have for multiple comma separated auto complete suggestion.. any idea sir.. thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how the plugin works. If you add the value to the autocomplete textbox itself, then the next search term will include the previous item plus the new input and obviously there won't be any matches for it... If possible add the results to another textbox instead of the autocomplete itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me form this link http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/zMWLx/

```
var masterdata=["abc","pqr","rst"];
 $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#TestNames" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {

            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            masterdata, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
},
      select: function( event, ui ) {
                // Add the selected term appending to the current values 
with a comma
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // join all terms with a comma
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
              },
      focus: function() {
               // prevent value inserted on focus when navigating the drop 
down list
               return false;
             }
    });
  });
```